# Make DataTables totals row immune to sorting/filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable. I also add total in last tr. When I search any data by date range or datatable default search my total not showing. How can I fix it with search result total?

This is my script

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var min = $('#datepicker_from').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#datepicker_to').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(data[1]);
                    if (min == null && max == null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            );


            $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
                onSelect: function () {
                    table.draw();
                },
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true

            });
            $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
                onSelect: function () {
                    table.draw();
                }, changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true

            });
            var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

            // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
            $('#datepicker_from, #datepicker_to').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use table's `<tfoot>` row to display totals?

Comment: Using `<tfoot>` to display totals will make it immune to sorting/filtering. However, you may use some attribute, say, `class="totals"` to the totals row while rendering it and than append to your if's within `ext.search`, something, like `if($(table.row(dataIndex).node()).hasClass('totals')) return true;`.

Comment: Can you put full code?

Comment: Can you post yours? It's around 40% of your code describing datepickers logic which is not relevant to your question, but there's nothing about data structure: (which field you calculate your totals by? Is it sum or average? Is it always totals over entire table or over visible rows only? Which way you use to construct those totals row?). Those are questions that I need you to answer, in order to understand your app's logic and structure and post wider code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering, you didn't share certain prerequisites, I'll allow myself to make up my own example.

So, as being said, optimal solution of your problem would be to place your totals into `<tfoot>` row, so they're not getting affected neither by filtering nor by sorting:

```js
//source data
const srcData = [
  {item: 'apple', order: '12/03/2019', cost: 15},
  {item: 'pear', order: '24/10/2018', cost: 24},
  {item: 'banana', order: '13/02/2019', cost: 14},
  {item: 'plum', order: '11/12/2018', cost: 26}
];
//DataTable initialization
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'Item', data: 'item'},
    {title: 'Order date', data: 'order'},
    {title: 'Cost', data: 'cost'}
  ],
  drawCallback: () => {
 //append tfoot and populate it with total cost
 $('#mytable tfoot').remove();
 $('#mytable').append(`<tfoot><td colspan="3" style="text-align:right"><b>Total cost:</b> ${$('#mytable').DataTable().column(2, {search:'applied'}).data().toArray().reduce((sum, item) => sum+=item, 0)}</td></tfoot>`);
  }
});
//custom date range filter
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row) => (new Date(row[1].split('/').reverse()) >= new Date($('#startdate').val().split('/')) || $('#startdate').val() == '') && 
 (new Date(row[1].split('/').reverse()) <= new Date($('#enddate').val().split('/')) || $('#enddate').val() == ''));
//bind 'from' / 'to' inputs
$('input[type="date"]').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'startdate') $('#enddate').attr('min', $(this).val());
  else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'enddate') $('#startdate').attr('max', $(this).val());
  dataTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <label>from:</label>
  <input type="date" id="startdate"></input>
  <label>to:</label>
  <input type="date" id="enddate"></input>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if, for some reason, you wish to keep your totals as a regular row on the bottom of `<tbody>`, you may change `drawCallback` to append totals row upon each redraw to secure totals row persistence, or attach `id` attribute to it and pass totals row through your custom filter.

If former is preferred, you may simply change `drawCallback` option (back to my example) for:

```
  drawCallback: () => {
    //append row to tbody and populate it with total cost
    $('#mytable #totals').remove();
    $('#mytable tbody').append(`<td id="totals" colspan="3" style="text-align:right"><b>Total cost:</b> ${$('#mytable').DataTable().column(2, {search:'applied'}).data().toArray().reduce((sum, item) => sum+=item, 0)}</td>`);
  }
```

If latter option is more suitable for you, and you construct your totals row with `id="totals"`, the filter (again, back to my example) would look like (pay attention to the last row):

```
//custom date range filter
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row, index) => (new Date(row[1].split('/').reverse()) >= new Date($('#startdate').val().split('/')) || $('#startdate').val() == '') && 
    (new Date(row[1].split('/').reverse()) <= new Date($('#enddate').val().split('/')) || $('#enddate').val() == '')) 
    || $(dataTable.row(index).node()).is('#totals');
```